# Copy file to a folder based on folder created from file

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that looks in a directory and if any .xlsx file types are there it creates a folder based on the filename of each xlsx file type and copies the file to each folder. That part works. What I need to do now is copy files from \\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation\Staging to each folder when it is created.

Here is my code:

```
$SourceFolder = "\\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation"
$TargetFolder = "\\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
    $ChildPath = Join-Path -Path $_.Name.Replace('.xlsx','') -ChildPath $_.Name

    [System.IO.FileInfo]$Destination = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $ChildPath

    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $Destination.Directory.FullName)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Destination.Directory.FullName
    }

    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Destination.FullName
    Copy-Item -Path "\\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation\Staging\Compliance Webinar Certificate Template (1).docx" -Destination $Destination -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "\\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation\Staging\Email Mail Merge for Certificates.docx" -Destination $Destination -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "\\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation\Staging\Manual Attendee Info List.xlsx" -Destination $Destination -Force
}
```

Comment: What is your question? ;) Hint: If you want to copy the same files into each folder, you have to move the `Copy-Item` inside your foreach loop.

Comment: I need to copy the 3 files in \\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation\Staging to the folder created. I can't get it to copy even when I put the syntax in the loop.

Comment: I suggest you write a script and hard code all of your values, then 1 by 1 parameterize them, add in your loop etc.  I also suggest you try to avoid mixing calls into the platform with PowerShell commands.  For example Test-Path has a parameter that you can pass that tell it to report the status of a filename vs. a directory.

Listing any error messages you get would be helpful too

Comment: Can you give me an example or a link of what you mean? I'm fairly new to Powershell code and want to figure this out.

Comment: Have you tried to change the `-Destination` to `$Destination.FullName` as it is in the first copy action that is sucessful

Comment: It is set to $Destination.FullName

Comment: And what's happening? Syntax looks just fine to me. Any errors? The first copy action succeeds, the last three don't? For every folder?

Comment: That is correct. The last three Copy-Item lines don't copy the files over. No errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you are overcomplicating things, to append the name without extenson simply `Join-Path $TargetPath $_.BaseName`

To reduce redundancy with same long pathes use the variable you already defined.

```
$SourceFolder = "\\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation"
$TargetFolder = "\\paculfs3\Deptfiles\SharedFiles\Compliance\Certification Creation"

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceFolder -Filter *.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
    $Destination = Join-Path -Path $TargetFolder -ChildPath $_.BaseName
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Destination -Force | Out-Null
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $Destination
    Copy-Item -Path "$SourceFolder\Staging\Compliance Webinar Certificate Template (1).docx" -Destination $Destination -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "$SourceFolder\Staging\Email Mail Merge for Certificates.docx" -Destination $Destination -Force
    Copy-Item -Path "$SourceFolder\Staging\Manual Attendee Info List.xlsx" -Destination $Destination -Force
}
```